# Creating a new associative array using values of the nested multi dimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have following multi dimensional array, I'm getting this from an API via curl request.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => David Warner
            [type] => batter
            [country] => Aus
            [age] => 33
            [runs] => 11100
            [wickets] => 12
            [catches] => 16
            [format] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [Domestic] => Array
                                        (
                                          [0] => Array
                                            (
                                             [ODI]   => 73
                                             [Tests] => 34
                                             [T20]   => 90   
                                            )
                                         )
                         
                        )
                )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Mark Wood
            [type] => bowler
            [country] => Eng
            [age] => 34
            [runs] => 200
            [wickets] => 120
            [catches] => 2
            [format] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [Domestic] => Array
                                        (
                                          [0] => Array
                                            (
                                             [ODI]   => 40
                                             [Tests] => 49
                                             [T20]   => 12   
                                            )
                                         )
                         
                        )
                )
       )
)
```

I'm trying to create a new array which includes only the "[T20]" values.

My desired out put should look similar to the following array

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => "90"
  1 => "12"

]
```

So far, I've tried following methods...

```
$newArr_t20 = array_column($result_3['cricketers']['player']['format']['Domestic'], "T20");
```

Since I'm using laravel then I tried following as well,

```
use \Illuminate\Support\Arr;

$newArr_t20 = Arr::pluck($result_3, 'cricketers.player.format.Domestic.T20');
```

But nothing is working for me...

Comment: Please always endeavour to provide a [mcve]. While it is important that readers understant the general structure of your input array, it unmecessarily bloats your question body to include every element that exists in your actual application data.  All of those 2nd level associative elements are unneeded.  Please provide your input array as copy-pasted output text from `var_export()` so that contributors can immediately apply it to their coding attempts.

Answer (score 0):

Using Laravel the collection helper [`Collection::flatten()`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-flatten) should be the right way;

```
$data = collect($apiData)->flatten(4)->pluck('T20')->all();
```

Explanation:

1. Transform your array into a collection to be able to use the Laravel collection's provided helpers:

   `collect($apiData)`
2. Transform your multidimensional array into a single dimensional one, which is nothing more than the array at the n-th depth (4 here in this case):

   `collect($apiData)->flatten(4)`
3. Map this array into an array having only the values of the `T20` key

   `collect($apiData)->flatten(4)->pluck('T20')`
4. Get the array representation of the collection

   `collect($apiData)->flatten(4)->pluck('T20')->all()`

Comment: Is this solution provable via the Laravel playground? I don't Laravel, so I don't know whether this correct-looking answer is actually correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$array = 'Your array...';

$t20_values = [];

foreach ($array as $value) {
    foreach ($value['format'] as $format) {
        foreach ($format['Domestic'] as $domestic) {
            if (isset($domestic['T20'])) {
                $t20_values[] = $domestic['T20'];
            }
        }
    }
}

dd($t20_values);
```

Comment: Please avoid posting "try this" answers on Stack Overflow.  Explained answers are always more helpful than unexplained answers.  By including a compelling reason for use and an explanation of how the snippet works, you educate the asker, educate future researchers, and improve the searchability of content on this site.